# How to block connection request from already paired devices(phones) using bluez?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, a2dp

As per my knowledge, Bluez does not have non-connectable property **(except Block property)** to block the classic BT connection request from the devices (phones) which already paired with.

**Case:** My speaker should not allow any a2dp connection request (paired phone 2) while actively connected with phone 1. But it should allow BLE connection at any time.

I can achieve this by checking the connected property changed with (org.bluez.Device1), But the thing is, All connection request comes with org.bluez.Device1 and then org.bluez.MediaControl1 (Classic BT - A2DP). How can i variate the connection request here ?
I am using Bluez 5.49. Is there any option to achieve non connectable ?